# How to reuse the same img without multiple server calls?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a vuejs component named `gallery` that includes a lot of `galleryItem` child components, now galleyItem has an common `<img>` element that loads an arrow png, this png is same for every galleryItem, and I am adding the element in traditional html way `<img href="#" src="assets/img/Arrow.png">` in all iteration of `galleryItem`.

My question is, does it mean, for every `galleryItem` there will be a separate call to the server for this arrow image? If so, is it possible to load the img with only a single call to server and reuse the same arrow image in every `galleryItem` component?

Comment: The browser will cache that image for you. It uses the URL as a cache key.

Comment: Open up the network panel and watch what the browser does when you load many of those images in the same view.

Comment: browser by default cache same request , u can what this request in network tab in chrome so if u call one image in multiple section or even next pages browser check your cache and load from your disk